# Subview loading from storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am beginner in ios development. I created a tab bar controller in storyboard. In one of the tabs, I added a table view with custom cells in storyboard with a map view on top created in code. When user presses on the map view, it slides down pushing down the table view. All is fine except when I go to other tab and come back to the tab, the table view is back up with its frame from storyboard. Can some one suggest how to prevent this?

Comment: set a flag value. and use it in ViewWillAppear method to check its value to set the frame of the TableView and MapView Accordingly.